# Is this an easter egg of Google Docs?

Tags: google-docs

So today is Friday for me and I notice something -

> https://docs.google.com/document/u/1/?**tgif**=d

tgif- Thank God it's Friday

Is it an easter egg or some kind of actual parameter?

Comment: Besides the URL parameter do you notice non-ordinary something else? Searching google docs tgif returns similar reports made on reddit, twitter,etc. but I didn't found anything reporting non-ordinary features. By the way, the same parameter but with different values on  Forms, Sheets, Slides but not on Apps Scripts.

Comment: No, everything was  working fine

Comment: Google has so many Easter eggs they may as well just post an entire list of them somewhere ;)

Answer (score 3):

It could be an easter egg by itself. AFAIK Google haven't published it on the [official documentation](https://support.google.com/docs), by the other hand, the APIs and Google Apps Script Services for Google editors can only interact with files not with the GUI of the file lists.

Update: Today is Sunday and going to https://sheets.google.com redirect me to

```
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/u/0/?tgif=d
```

and the same on https://docs.google.com, the destination URL ends on `?tgif=d`